Great Expectations - KeyError: "Neither config : (...) nor config_defaults : {} contains a module_name key
I'm new to GX and I'm trying to test the connections defined in my great_expectations.yml.
This is the function that I'm trying to run under airflow in a local docker environment:
def test_ge_data_context_connections():
    context = ge.data_context.DataContext()

    # Test each datasource
    for datasource in context.list_datasources():
        datasource_name = datasource['name']
        logging.info(f"Testing connection for datasource: {datasource_name}...")
        try:
            datasource_config = context.get_datasource(datasource_name)
            datasource_yaml = yaml.dump(datasource_config.config)

            connection_test_result = context.test_yaml_config(datasource_yaml)

ERROR:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/config_validator/yaml_config_validator.py", line 556, in _test_instantiation_of_misc_class_from_yaml_config
    instantiated_class = instantiate_class_from_config(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/util.py", line 42, in instantiate_class_from_config
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "Neither config : ordereddict([('data_connectors', ordereddict([('default_runtime_data_connector_name', ordereddict([('batch_identifiers', ['default_identifier_name']), ('class_name', 'RuntimeDataConnector'), ('module_name', 'great_expectations.datasource.data_connector'), ('name', 'default_runtime_data_connector_name')])), ('s3_bucket_data_connector', ordereddict([('assets', ordereddict([('tasks_data_asset', ordereddict([('base_directory', 's3://***/data/DEV/Tasks'), ('class_name', 'Asset'), ('group_names', ['file']), ('module_name', 'great_expectations.datasource.data_connector.asset'), ('pattern', '(.*)')]))])), ('bucket', '***'), ('class_name', 'ConfiguredAssetS3DataConnector'), ('module_name', 'great_expectations.datasource.data_connector'), ('name', 's3_bucket_data_connector'), ('prefix', 'data/DEV')]))])), ('execution_engine', ordereddict([('class_name', 'PandasExecutionEngine'), ('module_name', 'great_expectations.execution_engine')])), ('id', None), ('name', 's3_datasource')]) nor config_defaults : {} contains a module_name key."

great_expectations.yml config that I'm testing:
datasources:
  s3_datasource:
    class_name: Datasource
    module_name: great_expectations.datasource
    execution_engine:
      class_name: PandasExecutionEngine
      module_name: great_expectations.execution_engine
    data_connectors:
      default_runtime_data_connector_name:
        name: default_runtime_data_connector_name
        class_name: RuntimeDataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        batch_identifiers:
          - default_identifier_name
      s3_bucket_data_connector:
        name: s3_bucket_data_connector
        class_name: ConfiguredAssetS3DataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        assets:
          tasks_data_asset:
            class_name: Asset
            module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector.asset
            base_directory: ${Storage}/Tasks
            pattern: (.*)
            group_names:
              - file
        bucket: ${S3_BUCKET}
        prefix: ${S3_PREFIX}
        creds:
          access_key: airflow
          secret_key: airflow
  data_warehouse:
    class_name: Datasource
    module_name: great_expectations.datasource
    execution_engine:
      class_name: SqlAlchemyExecutionEngine
      module_name: great_expectations.execution_engine
      connection_string: ${DATA_WAREHOUSE}
    data_connectors:
      default_runtime_data_connector_name:
        name: default_runtime_data_connector_name
        class_name: RuntimeDataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        batch_identifiers:
          - default_identifier_name
      default_inferred_data_connector_name:
        name: default_inferred_data_connector_name
        class_name: InferredAssetSqlDataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        include_schema_name: true
        introspection_directives:
          schema_name: "public"
      default_configured_data_connector_name:
        name: default_configured_data_connector_name
        class_name: ConfiguredAssetSqlDataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        assets:
          Tasks:
            class_name: Asset
            module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector.asset
            schema_name: "public"
            data_asset_name: "Tasks"          
config_variables_file_path: uncommitted/config_variables.yml

I'm having the same error for both S3 and Postgresql datasources.
Versions:

Airflow 2.9.2
Great Expectations 0.18.16
python 3.11.9

Thank you
I want to test the connections prior to start validating great_expectations checkpoints.

You shouldn't be using great_expectations.yml to connect to data sources in v0.18. Check out the docs on connecting to S3 using the Python API: https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/oss/guides/connecting_to_your_data/fluent/filesystem/connect_filesystem_source_data
